# Word 2016 for Mac is truncating the PDF page

Tags: macos, ms-office, pdf

When I try to "Save as PDF" a single-page, 8.5" x 14" Microsoft Word 2016 document, it's cutting off the edge. Does anyone know how to resolve this? It almost seems as if 8.5" x 11" (standard letter size) is hard-coded into the PDF driver for Microsoft Office 2016.

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT**: If I try to Print the document, the print preview window is empty.

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: As a work-around, you could print -> save as pdf. 'Hard coded' is usually a pretty safe assumption to make when discussing Microsoft

Comment: @agentroadkill: I got a completely blank document using that method, but it appears to be the right size.

Comment: Hmm... Okay final test: file > print preview, then print. Does the preview look like it should or is it poorly sized or blank as well?

Comment: The print preview is showing up empty, too. Weird. :-\

Comment: I noticed in your edit there is no printer selected. Do you get different behavior if you select a printer before trying to generate the pdf?

Comment: @agentroadkill: Good idea, but I don't have any printers installed. Maybe my best bet is to use a virtual PDF printer driver. I've sent feedback to Microsoft using their built-in happy/sad-face tool.

Comment: Happy/sadface is an excellent way to describe difficult UI issues. A virtual printer is probably your next trouble shooting step until you get feedback